# How to identify if the child window has been closed in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, refresh

i have this page which opens up a popup. i want to refresh the parent after popup has been closed.. i used the function i found in stackoverflow

```
  var win = window.open("popup.html");

function doStuffOnUnload() {
     alert("Unloaded!");
  }

if (typeof win.attachEvent != "undefined") {
    win.attachEvent("onunload", doStuffOnUnload);
} 
else if (typeof win.addEventListener != "undefined") {
    win.addEventListener("unload", doStuffOnUnload, false);
}
```

which didn't do anything after i closed the pop up... what can i do achieve this?
thanks...

Comment: Inside your popup.html....hv you tried this.. <body unload="yourfun()"> ???

Comment: @ShashankKadne Should be `window.opener.yourfun();`.

Comment: @RobW. Depends on what she is trying to do...

Answer (score 1):

You wrote the unload event in the wrong place. You added an unload event to the main page instead of to the popup...

```
 var win = window.open("popup.html"); // O.K.
```

All of this should be in the popup.html page...

```
function doStuffOnUnload() {
     alert("Unloaded!");
  }

 if (typeof win.attachEvent != "undefined") {
   win.attachEvent("onunload", doStuffOnUnload);
 } else if (typeof win.addEventListener != "undefined") {
  win.addEventListener("unload", doStuffOnUnload, false);
  }
```

You can use the `unload` jquery function:

```
$(window).unload(doStuffOnUnload);
```

`unload` [docs](http://api.jquery.com/unload/)