# javascript - reload parent window if child window was closed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to reload a parent window if child window get closed.

Here is my current code which opens a popup window, but it has not programmed for refresh parent window when it get closed. I dont know what code to add

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    jQuery('.top-buttons a').live('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        newwindow=window.open($(this).attr('href'),'','height=500,width=850');

        if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()}
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: So, Where are you stuck?

Comment: read question carefully, i need a code which refresh parent window if child get closed

Comment: It was difficult to dedeuce it from  original question.Now after edit it says so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
newwindow = window.open($(this).attr('href'), '', 'height=500,width=850');
newwindow.onbeforeunload = function () {
    console.log("popup closed")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access the parent window from the child window using window.opener : [example](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mydeveloperworks/blogs/hazem/entry/accessing_parent_window_elements_from_child_window_in_javascript5?lang=en)

So to reload the parent window just call window.opener.location.reload() [documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_reload.asp) when you handle the close event.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code on close event of the child window

```
      window.opener.location.reload();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use window.opener to access parent window and window.reload() to reload it when child window is closed.

Please refer below URLS:

[how to access parent window object using jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167455/how-to-access-parent-window-object-using-jquery)

[javascript: How Can a parent window know that its child window closed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240428/javascript-how-can-a-parent-window-know-that-its-child-window-closed)

Answer (score 0):

in the parent window define an unload event like

```
 function doStuffOnUnload() {
     alert("Unloaded!");
  }

 if (typeof win.attachEvent != "undefined") {
     newwindow.attachEvent("onunload", doStuffOnUnload);
 } 
 else if (typeof win.addEventListener != "undefined") {
    newwindow.addEventListener("unload", doStuffOnUnload, false);
  }
```

from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9248371/how-to-identify-if-the-child-window-has-been-closed-in-javascript) i took it from

Answer (score 0):

you need `window.opener`

```
window.opener.location.href = window.opener.location.href;
```

should be added to the closing event of the window.

Comment: as other users have suggested location.reload() will also get you there.